# About how to drop first columns from DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete the first column in my DataFrame, and I found the answer on the Internet. The answer is to delete columns 1, 2 and 4. I want to know why this line of code can delete columns and what is the role of axis here?

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1)
```

Comment: in a DataFrame, axis=1 means the columns, axis=0 is the index

Comment: Thank you for your help, may I ask one more question, what should I do if I want to delete duplicate columns in DataFrame?

Comment: Hard to answer without a specific example. You can try `df2 = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.duplicated()]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

your example works fine.

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1)
```

sometimes you'll see it like this:

```
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 3]], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Another way to accomplish this would be by typing the names of the column headers:

```
df.drop(['column 1', 'column 2', 'column name 3'], axis=1)
```

However, it is good practice to create a new data frame when dropping columns. If you run that cell again, you'll get errors.

```
df_dropped =  df.drop(['column 1', 'column 2', 'column name 3'], axis=1)
```

To answer your question about axis=1, it's the column headers.

| column 1 | column 2 | column name 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 44 |
| 99 | 42 | 33 |

Comment: Very clear, but I have a question, what does ‘inplace’ do in the second code block?

Comment: inplace=True modifies the original data. Anything else referencing that dataframe may have issues. You could think of it like ice cream, if you have a scoop of ice-cream on top of a cone, and then purposefully melt the ice cream, you can't get it back to the original state (scoop on the cone).